# Calculate a better price for Webform CiviCRM Payment Installments (Annual)

Tags: webform-civicrm

If I set up Webform CiviCRM to sell an annual membership

- 4 installments
- 1 payment a year
- Four years

It seems to work just fine as far as charging them for the first installment and then tracking the rest on the CiviCRM end.

However, the user sees this on the payment page of the webform:

[image]

Is there any way to either remove this completely and use Webform to just list their current charge, or a way to parse this into something that will let them know what they are actually paying right now? I don't think putting the number of installments next to the membership name is going to cut it.

CiviCRM 4.7

Is using something like https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculation_components viable for this?

Comment: We have successfully used https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator with civicrm webforms but can't say if it will achieve what you are specifically requiring

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. If I have the amount and the # of installments and terms, etc. I should be able to calculate a result on the Payment page. I'll submit an answer if I get one!

Comment: Hey @petednz-fuzion I think I am running into this issue now: https://www.drupal.org/project/sliderfield/issues/2564903#comment-12462550

Comment: Which relates to this: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator/issues/2393499

Just following in your footsteps!

Answer (score 2):

That’s still on the ToDo list. Can you open an issue for this in the Drupal queue? I’ve got a small PR related this that I need to submit - will have a look at how to resolve this as well.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2941495 this work?

Comment: I wonder if there is cheap CSS/JS hack I could use in the interim to move my project forward? I can hide the section, but how do I get the contribution amount from P1 onto P2 of the webform in a way? The webform_calculator module failed to do this.

Comment: if we could contribute a small $ amount to get this fixed it's on the table!

Comment: I hope to find some time this week!

Comment: wf_crm_webform_preprocess.inc             

changing to this seems like a dirty hack? would it work?          'data-amount' => $item['line_total'] / $item['qty'],

Comment: We really need some UI on the Webform CiviCRM admin page,

Recurring Payment Formatting. Display line item price (Y/N), Display Total Pledge Amount (Y/N), Display Number of Terms (Y/N), Display Number of Installments (Y/N)  - or something like that, or perhaps an interface for formatting that on the confirmation screen with tokens, or printing a table with ID/classes that could be manipulated easy, or put into a webform markup field. I tried using the built in webform tokens but couldn't get it to display these fields.

Comment: The contribution receipt is also affected by the way this handles the data